# Using reformulate with multiple inputs

Tags: r, dplyr, survey

### Short Question:

using reformulate I can generate the following:

```
reformulate(sprintf('interaction(%s)', "Q50_1"))
~interaction(Q50_1)
```

How do I create something like this without adding it to the string "Q50_1":

```
~interaction(Q50_1, gender=="F")
```

I could do this, but I want to add them as separate arguments.

```
reformulate(sprintf('interaction(%s)', "Q50_1, gender=='F'"))
~interaction(Q50_1, gender == "F")
```

### Full Question:

I am using the survey package svymean to produce the SE and cross table frequencies of weighted data. I am struggling with the the reformulate function.

This is my data:

```
data <- read_table2("Q50_1   Q50_2   Q38 Q90 pov gender  wgt id
yes   3   Yes NA   High    M   1.3 A
NA   4   No  2   Med F   0.4 B
no   2   NA 4   Low F   1.2 C
maybe   3   No  2   High    M   0.5 D
yes   NA   No  NA   High    M   0.7 E
no   2   Yes 3   Low F   0.56 F
maybe   4   Yes 2   Med F   0.9 G
")
```

Create the design object:

```
design <- svydesign(id =~id,
                        weights  = ~wgt,
                        nest = FALSE,
                        data = data)
```

User function to loop through columns names and generate the appropriate format to be read into the function. Example ["~interaction(Q50_1)"].

```
vars1 <- c("Q50_1", "Q38")

create_df<- function(design, vector_vars){
  
 
  # function to retrieve the weighted,  mean and se 
  myfun <- function(x){
    form <- reformulate(sprintf('interaction(%s)', x))
    cbind(as.data.frame(svymean(form, design, na.rm = T)))
  }
  

  
  final <- do.call(rbind, lapply(vector_vars, myfun))
  return(final) 
}

create_df(design, vars1)
```

This works as expected:

```
                             mean        SE
interaction(Q50_1)maybe 0.2713178 0.1932617
interaction(Q50_1)no    0.3410853 0.2233323
interaction(Q50_1)yes   0.3875969 0.2331215
interaction(Q38)No      0.3669725 0.2130455
interaction(Q38)Yes     0.6330275 0.2130455
```

This is what I ran before:

```
svymean(~interaction(Q50_1), design, na.rm = T)
```

But now I want to change the format so that I can run interaction on a specific value of a different column. For example, to run Q50_1 by Female:

```
svymean(~interaction(Q50_1, gender=="F"), design, na.rm = T)
```

Resulting output:
[image]

To automate the above, I tried adding a variable "column" to the abouve function, that would add to the "form" object, but reformulate does not behave as expected. Any suggestions for how I might achieve this?

### Attempt to add a second specification to the form object

```
create_df_new<- function(design, vector_vars, column){
  
  # function to retrieve the weighted,  mean and se 
  myfun <- function(x){
    form <- reformulate(sprintf('interaction(%s)', x, column))
    cbind(as.data.frame(svymean(form, design, na.rm = T)))
  }
  

  final <- do.call(rbind, lapply(vector_of_vars, myfun))
  return(final) 
}

create_df_new(design, vars1, "gender==F")
```

Comment: there is a typo in your code `vector_vars` and `vector_of_vars`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fmt` should match the number of arguments passed into `sprintf`.  In the OP's code, there is only a single `%s`, while the input is 'x' and 'column'.  Also, there is a difference between `"gender == F"` and `'gender == "F"'` while constructing the formula.  The former can check for `FALSE` values while the latter checks for the string "F"

```
library(survey)
create_df_new <- function(design, vector_vars, column){
  
  # function to retrieve the weighted,  mean and se 
  myfun <- function(x){
    form <- reformulate(sprintf('interaction(%s, %s)', x, column))
    cbind(as.data.frame(svymean(form, design, na.rm = TRUE)))
  }
  

  final <- do.call(rbind, lapply(vector_vars, myfun))
  return(final) 
}

create_df_new(design, vars1, 'gender=="F"')
```

-output

```
                                                mean         SE
interaction(Q50_1, gender == "F")maybe.FALSE 0.09689922 0.10433556
interaction(Q50_1, gender == "F")no.FALSE    0.00000000 0.00000000
interaction(Q50_1, gender == "F")yes.FALSE   0.38759690 0.23312149
interaction(Q50_1, gender == "F")maybe.TRUE  0.17441860 0.17253314
interaction(Q50_1, gender == "F")no.TRUE     0.34108527 0.22333227
interaction(Q50_1, gender == "F")yes.TRUE    0.00000000 0.00000000
interaction(Q38, gender == "F")No.FALSE      0.27522936 0.19411565
interaction(Q38, gender == "F")Yes.FALSE     0.29816514 0.24925980
interaction(Q38, gender == "F")No.TRUE       0.09174312 0.09968017
interaction(Q38, gender == "F")Yes.TRUE      0.33486239 0.21984468
```